# Why the result file of cscope found in quickfix window can't be showed in file explorer?

Tags: quickfix, cscope

When I configured cscope in vim, I have installed some plugins such as Minibufexplorer, but I found that when I use `cs find s`, the result could be showed in the quickfix, and none of the option file could be displayed in file explorer.

Why is that? and how to solve it. thanks!

[image]

Comment: `minibufexpl` hasn't been updated since [2004](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159).  There are forks of it that haven't been updated since [2013](https://github.com/weynhamz/vim-plugin-minibufexpl). Perhaps it shouldn't be such a surprise it doesn't work well with newer code.

Comment: Why do you expect those files to appear in MBE?